# How should I give the parameters to express.use without getting a type error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

In this code snippet in the use function the path string throws this error.

> Argument type string is not assignable to parameter type RequestHandler<RouteParameters>
>     Assigned type doesn't contain call signatures

How should I use the params properly?

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use('/test', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('<h1>Test</h1>');
});

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems to be correct, but 1 thing that's bugging me is the way you are importing express. If you are using `typescript` you should be importing like this

```
import express from 'express'
```

Comment: It threw an error when I tried to use it like that, but now I realized that I hasn't set type: "module" in the package.json. 

Could it be an InteliJ IDEA problem then? 

It looks like [this.](https://imgur.com/a/kDux5nF)

Comment: @Marko Best thing I can suggest at this point is to run `npm install` again

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're mixing commonjs modules with typescript/es6 modules.
They are compiled differently.
This is why you're gettings this error, because when you required express, it was not resolved to the correct function that can be executed for you get a instance of express app.

In order make compatibility between different types of modules, you must configure typescript.

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "node_modules/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I tried setting up the tsconfig and using import instead of const, but the issue still persists.